# Couchbase filter on pull replication c#

Tags: c#, couchdb, couchbase-lite

Trying to add pull filter in Couchbase Lite...

Added filter in design document

```
"filters": {
       "user": "function(doc,req) { if(doc.type == 'user' && email == req.query.email) {return true;} return false;}"
   }
```

In C# replicatoin code added following:

```
pull.Filter = "myview/user";
pull.FilterParams = new Dictionary<string, object> { { EnumUtil.UserDocument.email.ToString (), App.user.email }};
```

Filter work sometimes but not always...

How to add pull filter correctly or any other way to replicate user specific data to app using Couch? Channel will not help as I may have many users and need to show data only for specific user...

Comment: Are you using the [couchbase-lite-net](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-net) library? Looks like you are trying to pull from CouchDB to Couchbase Lite. I don't think filter functions are supported for that use case in CB Lite. I'd suggest using Sync Gateway which has the concept of a [sync function](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/sync-gateway/sync-function-api-guide/intro/index.html) to only pull documents belonging to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For filtering in Couchbase Lite, the parameter values are specified in the 'Replication.filterParams' property as a dictionary and passed into the filter function where it would match only docs with the specified given owner' property.

Can also reference the [Replication Guide](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html) for more in-depth examples and discussions on the topic.